# Devo definir o background na TD ou na TR?

Tags: html, css

Tenho esse questionamento desde sempre. Queria saber qual é a forma mais recomendada, se é definir o  `background` na `tr` ou na `td`.

Exemplo 1

```
.table > thead > tr {
      background: red;
 }
```

Exemplo 2:

```
.table > thead > tr > td {
      background: red;
 }
```

Nos exemplos acima, qual será o mais recomendado?

Há alguma tipo de especificação quanto a isso, ou fica a meu critério?

Comment: No TR se quiser que fique na linha, no TD ou TH se quiser que fique na célula ;)

Answer (score 2):

Uma diferença que vejo entre os dois é que aplicando o estilo à linha sempre será a toda a linha, tendo como vantagem construir um efeito "zebrado":

```
.table>thead>tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

**Zebrado**

```css
.table>thead>tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Aplicando aos *table data* (`<td>`), é possível aplicar estilos a específicas células da tabela, como o uso do `nth-child`:

```
.table>thead>tr>td:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
```

**Exemplo**

```css
.table>thead>tr>td:nth-child(1) {
      background: red;
    }
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

E quando se está utilizando `thead` fica mais semântico usar `<th>` ao invés de `<td>`, por se referir a *Table Header*.

Answer (score 0):

Depende um pouco do objetivo.
Ao definir dentro da "td" o seu background pode ficar "falhado" quando tiver algum espaçamento entre as tds como um padding.
Colocando dentro da tr você não teria esse tipo de problema, além do que você poderia sobreescrever algum background em alguma td específica conforme a necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

As tags `<td>` e `<th>` são células da tabela, e o `<tr>` são linhas, além deles existem elementos que são usados como "divisores", sendo o `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>` e `<thead>`

- [`<th>` table header cell](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/th.html) indica que deve conter uma texto ou uma descrição
- [`<td>` table data cell](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/td.html) indica que deve conter dados

> **Nota:** `<th>` não precisa estar necessariamente dentro de tfoot ou thead, pode ser usado dentro de tbody

Um [`<tr>` (table-row)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/tr.html) é uma linha e está linha pode ter várias células, um `<th>` ou `<td>` são células, mas não podem conter outras tags de tabela diretamente como filha, a não ser a própria tag `<table>` o que iria gerar uma nova tabela.

Então quando você colore o `<tr>` na verdade você está colorindo a linha toda, se as celulas não tiverem cor então serão transparentes e irá parecer que coloriu tudo:

```css
.table {
   width: 100%;
}
.table tr {
    background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

No caso você só nota as bordas (espaçamentos) entre as celulas porque o padrão do tipo da tabela é por padrão é `border-collapse: separate;`, mas se ajustar para `border-collapse: collapse;`, veja a diferença:

```css
.table {
   width: 100%;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table tr {
    background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> Nos exemplos acima, qual será o mais recomendado?

Não necessariamente, se quer colorir a linha toda pode-se usar ambos seletores, visualmente terão o mesmo efeito, mas é como disse, um irá colorir as células e o outro irá colorir a linha, ou seja será o elemento "pai", o que pode ter variações nos efeitos desejados, se quiser fazer um efeito zebra com `hover` seria mais fácil usar diretamente no `<tr>`

```css
.table {
   width: 100%;
}
.table tr {
    background: #c0c0c0;
}
.table tr:hover {
    background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

É claro que pode atingir o mesmo efeito do `tr` fazendo assim:

```css
.table {
   width: 100%;
}
.table tr td {
    background: #c0c0c0;
}
.table tr:hover td {
    background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Se quiser animar o hover na celula faça assim:

```css
.table {
   width: 100%;
}
.table tr {
    background: #c0c0c0;
}
.table td:hover {
    background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Isso só seria mais interessante se quiser um efeito por exemplo com `nth-child`

> Há alguma tipo de especificação quanto a isso, ou fica a meu critério?

Tecnicamente no CSS não tem limitações pré-definidas, basta entender a diferença de ambos, linha e celula.